# Error when Exporting Syncfusion grid grouping control

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel, syncfusion

I've been trying to convert a syncfusion grid to excel but a `NullReferenceException` error gets popping up.

This is my code :

```
        GroupingGridExcelConverterControl converter = null;

        try
        {
            string filePath = DirectoryHelper.GetDirectoryPath(DirectoryHelper.TempDirectory);
            filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, "Excel" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HHmmss") + ".xls");

            converter = new GroupingGridExcelConverterControl();
            converter.CaptionBackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            converter.ExportStyle = false;

            converter.ExportElement += new GroupingGridExcelConverterControl.GridExportElementEventHandler(converter_ExportElement);

            converter.GroupingGridToExcel(this.grid, filePath, Syncfusion.GridExcelConverter.ConverterOptions.Default);

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
            proc.Start();
            converter.ExportElement -= new GroupingGridExcelConverterControl.GridExportElementEventHandler(converter_ExportElement);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RootServiceProvider.ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);

        }
        finally
        {
            converter.ExportElement -= new GroupingGridExcelConverterControl.GridExportElementEventHandler(converter_ExportElement); ;
            converter.Dispose();
        }
```

- Exception is throwing from the line :

  `converter.GroupingGridToExcel(this.grid, filePath, Syncfusion.GridExcelConverter.ConverterOptions.Default);`
- I'm using VS 2010, .net 4.0 & Syncfusion 6.4.0.15
- Stack Trace of the exception :

> Syncfusion.GroupingGridExcelConverter.GroupingGridExcelConverterControl.ExportColumnHeader(GridColumnHeaderRow
>   headerRow, IWorksheet sheet, Element element, Int32 index,
>   ConverterOptions options, Int32 iGroupLevel, Int32& iSkipCount)    at
>
> > Syncfusion.GroupingGridExcelConverter.GroupingGridExcelConverterControl.ExportElements(IList
> >     arrElements, IWorksheet sheet, Int32 index, ConverterOptions options,
> >     Int32 iGroupLevel)    at
> >     Syncfusion.GroupingGridExcelConverter.GroupingGridExcelConverterControl.GroupingGridToExcel(GridGroupingControl
> >     grouping, IWorksheet sheet, ConverterOptions options)    at
> >     Syncfusion.GroupingGridExcelConverter.GroupingGridExcelConverterControl.GroupingGridToExcel(GridGroupingControl
> >     grouping, String strFileName, ConverterOptions options)    at
> >     Mubasher.NetPlus.Shared.Module.CommonToolBarContainer.ExportGGCToExcel()

- Any insights on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed your reported issue at our end. We could not able to reproduce your reported scenario. We need some more details regarding your customization on **ExportElements** event and sample screenshot of application. So that we can try based on that.

**Note:**
Please create a DT incident for your query for better followup.

You can create the DT incident from the following link.
http://www.syncfusion.com/account/dashboard